# Jenkins executors configuration mismatch

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Recently I see some strange behavior with Jenkins, configured to use 5 executors (on master) only, but despite the configuration, I see this:

[image]

My build queue has few hundreds of jobs waiting and dispatching correctly.
But I can't understand why there are so many running jobs on my master if only 5 executors configured?

Running Jenkins ver. 2.89.1

Comment: Follow this post for more info [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20107](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20107)

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy it looks like very old thread for Jenkins 1.5, and the issue has not resolved it just became "hard to reproduce"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Pipeline jobs. All the pipeline code which is not inside a `node` is executed in a Jenkins master thread and it's shown in the UI as an executor, usually called *lightweight executor*. They do not consume a real executor in a node.

This is why your pipelines should not do any heavy work other than orchestrating the build. Any real build (calls to build tools, computation or resources demanding tasks) should be done inside a `node` block.